# Do we need to do session.begin() explicitly?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Specifically, do I need to call `begin` after doing a commit or rollback? I saw stuff suggesting that a new session **always enters** `begin` state; but I was wondering about auto-committed transactions happening when a session is begun.

When must I issue a `begin`? Will multiple `begin`s in same session behave the same as in a MySQL terminal?

I have cases like (look at comments):

--1 A method that does transactions in a loop:

```
for ...: #EACH ONE DESERVES TO HAVE OWN TRANSACTION
  session.begin()
  for ....:
    session.execute("insert into...")
  session.commit()
```

--2 A function that calls another function in same session:

```
def f1(): #can be done standalone
  session = Session()
  session.begin()
  ...do stuff
  session.commit()

def f2():
  session = Session()
  session.begin()
  a = session.execute("select...")
  if stuff_not_fine():
    session.rollback() #KILL OF CURRENT TRANSACTION
    f1()
    session.begin() #CONTINUE WHERE IT LEFT
  a = session.execute("select...")
  ...do rest of stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

A SQL connection is as well a context manager. So you can do

```
session = Session()
with session as cursor:
    # do stuff
```

In order to roolback, you might introduce an exception which, if raised, causes the context manager to rollback the transaction. You should remember to catch the exception, however.